# TextBox vertical alignment in Windows Store App

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I'm trying to do something that seems quite simple but that I haven't been able to do so far : Vertically align the text in a TextBox in Windows Store App (XAML).

VerticalContentAlignment doesn't work (although it works well in WPF). I've even tried to extract the template and change it. Still couldn't do it.

Does anyone know how to do it ?

Comment: Add the textbox in Row for the grid and align your grid rows .`<TextBox Text="TestText"
Height="80"
Grid.Row="1"/>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no simple way. However if your TextBox has a fixed size then you can adjust the Padding Property in a custom style, it can be done dynamically too, but it is a bit more work.

```
 <Style TargetType="TextBox" x:Key="CustomTextBoxStyle">
        <Setter Property="Padding"
                Value="25" />
 </Style>
<TextBox Text="TestText"
             Height="80"
             Style="{StaticResource CustomTextBoxStyle}" />
```

[image]

Comment: Ok. I created a dummy TextBlock with the same text properties as the TextBox (Font family, size, style, weight), got its ActualHeight, substract it from the TextBox's height and divided by 2, and finally substract by the border thickness of the TextBox. I set this value as Padding. Ugly way to do it but it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can try this one also...

```
<Grid>
<TextBox Text="Centered Text" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/></Grid>
```